# Add JavaScript to NewForm sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, newform

I create new form with info path for sharepoint 2013 list,
I need to get current week from system calendar. I have javascript to do that!! but I have no idea that where is code must be add?
I open list by sharepoint designer 2013. these code must be add to NewForm or Views??

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add you javascript code to NewForm.aspx.
Place this code in the newform.aspx page under the line

```
 <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"> 

<!--  dkf code modified to redirect page  end -->


      </div>
      <div class="mainContent">

<!--  dkf code modified to redirect page -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function PreSaveAction() {
 var srcUrl=GetSource();
 var newSrcUrl = "http://www.yournewaddress.com";
 var i = aspnetForm.action.lastIndexOf(srcUrl);
 aspnetForm.action = aspnetForm.action.substring(0,i) + newSrcUrl ;
 return true;
 }
</script>
<!--  dkf code modified to redirect page  end -->
```

Another option would be like this:

From the Ribbon click on List -> Form Web Parts -> Default New Form
Click on Add a Web Part -> Media and Content -> Content Editor
Edit the Content Editor web part and put in the link to the JavaScript file

[Sharepoint 2013. Add JS to NewForm.aspx of a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45194/sharepoint-2013-add-js-to-newform-aspx-of-a-list)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351162/add-javascript-to-newform-for-splist-in-sharepoint

Comment: Hi, Can I use <SharePoint:ScriptLink /> inside PlaceHolderMain?

Comment: Hi, what's the point of the line?:
var i = aspnetForm.action.lastIndexOf(srcUrl);
From what I see debugging, aspnetForm.action is clean text whereas the GetSource() call returns a safe html encoded form of the string so the lastIndexOf call always returns -1